# vue-resource not passing token in request headers

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm new to Vuejs 2, currently using vue-resource to retrieve data from the server. However, I would need a token passed in the request header at the same time in order to retrieve the data from the server.

So the problem is, I am unable to retrieve data because the token is not passed into the request header, using vue-resource.

Here is the method that uses the vue-resource's interceptor (to pass in the token) to intercept the GET request:

```
test () {
  this.$http.interceptors.push((request) => {
    var accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    request.headers.set('x-access-token', accessToken)
    return request
  })
  this.$http.get(staffUrl)
   .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
   }, (response) => {
     console.log(response)
   })
}
```

Documentation for vue-resource, HTTP: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md

When I try to GET the data, i end up with an error 403 (forbidden) and after checking the request headers in the dev tools, I also could not find the token in the request headers.

Please tell me where I went wrong because I'm really new to this so i appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting interceptors inside the component using $http doesn't work, or at least it doesn't in my testing. If you examine/log `this.$http.interceptors` right after your push in the `test` method, you'll note that the interceptor was not added.

If you add the interceptor *before* you instantiate your Vue, however, the interceptor is added properly and the header will be added to the request.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
  var accessToken = "xyxyxyx"
  request.headers.set('x-access-token', accessToken)
  next()
})

new Vue({...})
```

Here is the [test code](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PjjPJO?editors=1010) I was using.

Also note, if you are using a version prior to 1.4, you should always call the *next* method that is passed to the interceptor. This does not appear to be necessary [post version 1.4](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/releases/tag/1.4.0).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! I was able to make it work after reading your explanation. I don't know whether it's a good idea but I put the `Vue.http.interceptors` in my main.js before instantiating Vue, then it worked :-)

Comment: @Bert What does next() function actually do? I cannot find any information on it on vue-resource documentation.

Comment: @CanolGökel It looks like they may have removed it from newer versions. Previously, interceptors took a next argument that called the next interceptor in the chain. https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/799819c8207419ea325fbd6deaf88c3890bbbe3c/docs/http.md#interceptors

Comment: @CanolGökel It looks like that happened in February of this year (2018). https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/releases/tag/1.4.0

Comment: I see, that explains why my code from last year was not working without the next() call :) I will update my vue-resource dependency on my project, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please go through this code

```
import vueResource from "vue-resource";
import { LocalStorage } from 'quasar'

export default ({
    app,
    router,
    Vue
}) => {
    Vue.use(vueResource);

    const apiHost = "http://192.168.4.205:8091/";

    Vue.http.options.root = apiHost;
    Vue.http.headers.common["content-type"] = "application/json";
    Vue.http.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + LocalStorage.get.item("a_t");



    Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {
        console.log("interceptors", request);
        next(function(response) {

        });
    });
}
```